# Getting "Expecting value" error from json.loads() when program encounters data

Tags: python, json, eclipse, argparse

I am using eclipse IDE and I'm passing json data through arguments. The problem is that the json data mentioned in the eclipse, run configuration, arguments is returning error when trying json.loads(). It is not a json file, it is just a simple json configuration.
The error is JSON decode error.

My input through the arguments in eclipse IDE: `--conf_json '{"data1":{"name":true}}'`.

While printing it in the program, I get: `'{data1:{name:true}}'`.
The double quotes are stripped on their own.

The error I get is: `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

```
import json
import argparse

main()
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='tbd')
parser.add_argument('conf-json', required=false, dest=conf_json, help='''json {"data":{"name":false}}'''

my_func(conf_json):
data=json.loads(conf_json)
```

My main issue is when the program encounters data, here in `json.loads()`, I get the error. If I print the json value, its double quotes are stripped off.

Please note: I can't change the IDE, will have to use eclipse.

Comment: Can you reformat your code , problem is not very clear from the explanation

Comment: I have made some edits that may more reflect what the author intended as sample code.    looks like its still missing an:   args = parser.parse_args() ;  conf_json = args.conf_json; 

# that will extract the passed value into the conf_json var.

Comment: `argparse` passes the string as given it in the `sys.argv`.  You can double check that.  Looks like the IDE is doing more than common shell.